# Conjuring daemons -- a fictive modern formula

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation, contemporary-latin

In it's "City of ..." book series (p. 300, I don't have the book name) Cassandra Clare let a person speak the formula "Quod tumeraris: per Jehovam, Gehennam et consecratam aquam quam nunc spargo, signumque crucis quod nunc facio, et per vota nostra, ipse nunc surgat nobis dictatus Azazel!",
to conjure a daemon. What is the correct translation?

My attempt is to see tumeraris as tumearis and translate ,, [At whom] Who is swollen: by God, Hell and the holy water which I now sprinkle, and by the sign of the cross which I now make as well as by our votes, may rise our dictator Azazel". But:

- Why should Hell and God "give the same order"?
- Is it correct that tumeraris is a misspelling?
- And why did the author use "dictatus" and not "dictator"?
  (I am open for improvements of the latin version as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an excerpt from a conjuring formula which is found in Christopher Marlowe's play [Doctor Faustus](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Tragedy_of_Doctor_Faustus), and which reads in full:

> Sint mihi dii Acherontis propitii! Valeat numen triplex Jehovoe! Ignei, aerii, aquatani spiritus, salvete! Orientis princeps
> Belzebub, inferni ardentis monarcha, et Demogorgon, propitiamus
> vos, ut appareat et surgat Mephistophilis Dragon, quod tumeraris: per Jehovam, Gehennam, et consecratam aquam quam nunc spargo,
> signumque crucis quod nunc facio, et per vota nostra, ipse nunc
> surgat nobis dicatus Mephistophilis!

As Scottish bibliophile and Marlowe commentator, [Alexander Dyce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Dyce) [remarks](https://www.google.de/books/edition/The_Works_Of_Christopher_Marlowe_With_No/MFpjAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&pg=PA18&printsec=frontcover): “There is a corruption here, which seems to defy emendation.” For the non-Latin *tumeraris* (you are, by the way, not improving things with the equally non-Latin *tumearis*), he mentions the suggested emendations *quod tu mandares* and *quod numen est aëris*. Elsewhere on the net I read *quid tu moraris?* I find none of these particularly convincing.

As you can see, it also says *dicatus* (devoted, dedicated, consecrated); for which *dicatis* has also been found in older prints, which could agree with *nobis*. In any event, Mephisto is no dictator.

It seems unlikely to me that this paragraph should be a proper reflection of Marlowe's latinity. The mangled Latin is perhaps the result of a parodistic intent, or of the publishing process. In any event, it is probably a hopeless undertaking trying to make sense of these bits of it.

Comment: Intentionally mangled Latin for comedic effect or to signal the limited education of the speaker is found in other early modern English plays. See the play Ignoramus by George Ruggle. Also, a lot of occult works produced in the middle ages and early modern period use language rather haphazardly, so Marlowe may be giving a historically accurate representation of occultism by butchering the incantation.

Comment: @Kingshorsey And it even has classical precedent with Petronius' *Satyricon*. Others have noted that Marlowe intentionally has comedic scenes throughout the play, but I'm no Marlowe scholar, so I can't opine on their legitimacy.